# Ports for testing Windows Server

Tags: asp.net, windows, windows-server-2012

I am currently working with **Windows Server 2012 R2** and was testing ports by assigning them to a published web site and just came out with this question, as a best practice or to align with standards, is there a ports range (Example from port 700 to port 3000) that is normally used to publish web sites for testing purposes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions about servers belongs on serverfault.com and is off topic here.